# Serial connection between Raspberry Pi and Roomba

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, robotics, roomba

I have a Raspberry Pi with [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718) FTDI cable and a Roomba 560. The Roomba has an SCI port to allow for control of the roomba via serial. I installed the PySerial library on the pi and send valid commands to Roomba, but the roomba doesn't respond. I have the TXD of the cable attached to the TXD of the roomba, the RXD on the cable wired to the RXD on the roomba, and a ground on the cable wired to the ground on the roomba (everything in  it's respective port). I do not have power going from the cable to the roomba or vice-versa.

What I can't figure out is why the commands aren't working. There's no error message upon running the python code. [This](http://www.irobot.com/images/consumer/hacker/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf) is the information sheet for the Roomba's SCI port.

Code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
# this is the defualt Roomba baud rate
ser.baudrate = 57600

# Start SCI - puts into safe mode
ser.write(chr(128))
# Enable full mode
ser.write(chr(131))
# Spot clean
ser.write(chr(134))

print 'Done'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .pdf spec for the SCI port is either outdated or incorrect, the 5XX series uses port 115200, that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the Pi and Roomba both talking on the same wire, and both listening on the other wire.

Connect the Pi's TX line to the Roomba's RX line, and vice versa.

First rule for troubleshooting serial communications: Swap connections on pins 2 and 3!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I switched the two and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The Roomba has a 'device detect' pin that you must pulse low to turn on the Roomba and initialize the connection. Sometimes people connect this to the RTS (or was it the CTS?) pin of the serial adapter. Device detect might be the same as pushing the Roomba's power button. After the Roomba prints the model and firmware version over the serial port it should be ready to receive commands.

I wouldn't recommend connecting the 5V device detect pin directly to the 3V Pi. You could just short it to ground manually (and briefly) to get started.